# Is there a way to disable eslint-mdx for code snippet in mdx files?

Tags: eslint, eslintrc

I've this mdx files and I am using `eslint-plugin-mdx` to lint mdx files (across all my tsx universe of files also linted with `eslint`).

In one of my mdx files, I've this code, it's a snippet of css

````
```css
@import '@namespace/theme-data'
@import '@namespace/theme-data2'

@import '@namespace/component-a/dist/theme'
@import '@namespace/component-c/dist/theme'
@import '@namespace/component-d/dist/theme'
@import '@namespace/component-z/dist/theme'
```
````

Currently linter is also affecting the snippet code, since it is part of an mdx file, and it restructures it like this

````
```css
@import '@namespace/theme-data' @import
  '@namespace/theme-data2' @import '@namespace/component-a/dist/theme'
  @import '@namespace/component-c/dist/theme' @import
  '@namespace/component-d/dist/theme' @import '@namespace/component-z/dist/theme';
```
````

- changing the indentation
- changing the lines
- adding a semicolon

This is a behaviour of the linter that I would like to disable, but I can't find a way.
Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was blind, being css, I need semicolons at the end of the line:

````
```css
@import '@namespace/theme-data';
@import '@namespace/theme-data2';

@import '@namespace/component-a/dist/theme';
@import '@namespace/component-c/dist/theme';
@import '@namespace/component-d/dist/theme';
@import '@namespace/component-z/dist/theme';
```
````

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how to do this via eslint (eslint-plugin-mdx):

```js
...
  overrides: [
    {
      files: "*.mdx",
      extends: ["plugin:mdx/recommended"],
      settings: {
        "mdx/code-blocks": false,
      },
    }
  ]
...
```